# Bash-skrip to delete whole xlf-tag

Tags: bash, sed

i try to delete an whole tag in an xlf-file like:

```
        <trans-unit id="test" resname="test">
            <source>Panels</source>
        </trans-unit>
```

Is there a way delete from string `<trans-unit id="test"` till string `</trans-unit>`?
I managed to delete two additional lines but it will be a problem on a multiline-value.

This is my current version:

```
sed -i.bak "/id=\"$KEY\"/,+2d" "$FILEPATH"
```

Comment: Probably `sed -i.bak '/<transunit id="'"$KEY"'"/,/<\/trans-unit>/d' "$FILEPATH"` will work.

Comment: There is just a "-" missing in "<transunit". If you post it like this: sed -i.bak '/<trans-unit id="'"$KEY"'"/,/<\/trans-unit>/d' "$FILEPATH" I can mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is well-indented, you can use a range pattern with `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak '/<trans-unit id="'"$KEY"'"/,/<\/trans-unit>/d' "$FILEPATH"
```

The command will find all lines between a line that contains `<trans-unit id=` + the ID in the `KEY` variable, and then `"` char, and a line that contains `</trans-unit>`, and then will delete the found line range(s) (due to the `d` flag).